# How to pass strings between C++ and javascript via emscripten

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

I am learning emscripten, and I can't even get the most basic string manipulation working, when passing strings between C++ and JS.

For example, I would like to write a string length function. In C++:

```
extern "C" int stringLen(std::string p)
{
    return p.length();
}
```

Called from javascript as:

```
var len = _stringLen("hi.");
```

This yields `0` for me. How do I make this work as expected? Which string type should I use here? `char const*`? `std::wstring`? `std::string`? None seem to work; I always get pretty random values.

This is only the beginning... How do I then *return* a string from C++ like this?

```
extern "C" char *stringTest()
{
    return "...";
}
```

And in JS:

```
var str = _stringTest();
```

Again, I cannot find a way to make this work; I always get garbage in JS.

So my question is clearly: How do I marshal string types between JS and C++ via Emscripten?

Comment: Related findings about the other direction of the problem (although this question is 7 years old):
This problem asks about passing a string from JavaScript to C++.
To pass a stiring FROM C++ to Javascript, one need `UTF8ToString`.

Answer (score 13):

extern "C" doesn't recognize std::string.

You may want to try this:
Test.cpp

```
#include <emscripten.h>
#include <string.h>

extern "C" int stringLen(char* p)
        {
            return strlen(p);
        }
```

Use the following command to compile the cpp code :

```
emcc Test.cpp -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_stringLen']
```

Sample test code :
Test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World !</title>
        <script src="a.out.js"></script>
        <script>
             var strLenFunction =  Module.cwrap('stringLen', 'number', ['string']);
             var len1 = strLenFunction("hi.");  // alerts 3
             alert(len1);
             var len2 = strLenFunction("Hello World"); // alerts 11
             alert(len2);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the complete question which was how to pass strings both to and from the C++ code.

Answer (score 8):

If you use extern "C" with a function, you cannot use C++ types in it's signature.

So if you want to use std::string, then you can use "Embind" or "WebIDL Binder". Refer [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#binding-c-and-javascript-webidl-binder-and-embind)

I prefer embind, so this is a sample code for your problem.

P.S I am not sure how to pass variables by reference here, so doing it by value.

```
// This is your routine C++ code
size_t MyStrLen(std::string inStr) {
    return inStr.length();
}

// This is the extra code you need to write to expose your function to JS
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
    function("MyStrLen", &MyStrLen);
}
```

Now in JS all you need to do is:

```
var myStr = "TestString";
Module.MyStrLen(myStr);
```

Make sure you pass the flag

> --bind

when calling emcc.

There is [another approach](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/4131) where you can do a Malloc on the C++ heap from JS and then do manipulations, but the above approach should be easier.

Comment: "If you use extern "C" with a function, you cannot use C++ types in it's signature." I see both answers claim this, but I don't think it's true. AFAIK this is just a linkage specification to prevent name mangling. I can compile `extern "C" void foo(std::string s) { std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl; }` just fine

Answer (score 5):

Other answers have not addressed how to return strings from C++. Here is a way to pass a string from c++ to javascript by passing a string by reference.

The emscripten documentation states the following about the types that can be passed to C/C++ functions using `cwrap`/`ccall` ([emscripten docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#calling-compiled-c-functions-from-javascript-using-ccall-cwrap)):

> The types are "number" (for a JavaScript number corresponding to a C integer, float, or general pointer), "string" (for a JavaScript string that corresponds to a C char* that represents a string) or "array" (for a JavaScript array or typed array that corresponds to a C array; for typed arrays, it must be a Uint8Array or Int8Array).

As the other answers have pointed out, you need to write the C function using a C string as the argument because that is the emscripten API (not because of `extern "C"`).

If you want to return a string, you may think that you can just pass a C string (effectively by reference because it is pointer) and modify that string:

```
// C function
extern "C" {
  void stringTest(char* output) {
    output[0] = 'H';
    output[1] = 'i';
  }
}

// Call to C function in javascript that does not modify output
let stringTestFunction =  Module.cwrap('stringTest', null, ['string']);
let output = "12"; // Allocate enough memory
stringTestFunction(output);
console.log(output); // 12
```

However, this does not work because a copy is created when passed to the function. So, you need to explicitly allocate the memory and pass a pointer instead. Emscripten provides the `allocateUTF8` and `UTF8ToString` functions for this purpose:

```
let stringTestFunction =  Module.cwrap('stringTest', null, ['number']); // the argument is 'number' because we will pass a pointer 
let output = "12";
let ptr = Module.allocateUTF8(output); // allocate memory available to the emscripten runtime and create a pointer
stringTestFunction(ptr);
output = Module.UTF8ToString(ptr); // read from the allocated memory to the javascript string
Module._free(ptr); // release the allocated memory
console.log(output); // Hi
```

Because we are transforming the string to a character pointer, we could have also called the function directly without using `cwrap` ([emscripten docs](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#call-compiled-c-c-code-directly-from-javascript)): `Module._stringTest(ptr)`. It requires some additional steps but now you have passed a string from C to javascript.

For this example to work, you may need to compile using the following flags: `-sEXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_stringTest','_malloc','_free']"` and `-sEXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['cwrap','allocateUTF8','UTF8ToString']"`.

There are more general ways to allocate memory for arrays of other types (https://stackoverflow.com/a/23917034/12510953).

Answer (score 3):

A few thoughts:

1. The only way I have called a method is by using `crwap` or
   `ccall`?
   `var length = Module.ccall('stringLen', ['string'], 'number');`
2. Are you including `stringLen` and `stringTest` in your `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS` parameter?
   `emcc hello_world.cpp ... -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_stringLen','_stringTest']`

Take a look here for more details:
http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html

Or my hello_world tutorial:
http://www.brightdigit.com/hello-emscripten/

Hopefully that helps.