# Pass array to C function with emscripten

Tags: c, arrays, emscripten

I think this question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883799/how-to-handle-passing-returning-array-pointers-to-emscripten-compiled-code) and I used most of it's answer for my problem, but I still have issues:

First the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C"
{
    void fillArray(int* a, int len)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<len; i++)
        {
            a[i] = i*i;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < len; ++j)
        {
            printf("a[%d] = %d\n", j, a[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm passing a pointer to an array to my C function and fill it with some information. I compile this code with

```
emcc -o writebmp.js dummyCode\cwrapCall.cxx -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_fillArray']"
```

My html/js code is the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <script src="writebmp.js"></script>
  <script>
    fillArray = Module.cwrap('fillArray', null, ['number', 'number']);
    var nByte = 4
    var length = 20;
    var buffer = Module._malloc(length*nByte);
    fillArray(buffer, length);
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        console.log(Module.getValue(buffer+i*nByte));
    }
  </script>
</html>
```

When I run the script the output I get is correct until the 12th element, after that it is garbage. Is the buffer I malloc too small?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Module.getValue` takes an optional second argument, denoting the type that the 'pointer' should be dereferenced as and by default this is `'i8'`, meaning the 32 bit signed integers are being dereferenced as 8 bit integers and so you're not getting garbage, but wrap around errors.

Fixing this is simple, you just need to specify that the 'pointer' passed to `Module.getValue` should be dereferenced as a 32 bit signed integer:

```
console.log(Module.getValue(buffer+i*nByte, 'i32'));
```

It might be safer and clearer to change the declaration of `fillArray` to

```
#include <stdint.h>

void fillArray(int32_t* a, int32_t len)
```

The revelant section of the emscripten docs can be found [here](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#access-memory-from-javascript)

Comment: I see there is no `getValue`