# Passing client files to webassembly from the front-end

Tags: javascript, html, c++, webassembly

I'm looking to pass user-submitted data to a c++ function which I've compiled to wasm. The data is a file which the user submits on the front end via an input tag, like so:

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.handleFile.bind(this)} />
```

The onChange callback currently looks like this:

```
handleFile(e){
    const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = evt => {
        window.Module.readFile(evt.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Finally, the .cpp file containing the readFile function looks like this:

```
void readFile(const std::string & rawString){
  std::vector<uint8_t> data(rawString.begin(), rawString.end());
  //...
}

EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
  emscripten::function("readFile", &readFile);
}
```

I've spend my afternoon reading various docs so I'm aware that I'm supposed to allocate memory for these files on the heap and then pass a ptr from js to readFile instead of passing all of the data. My problem is that I just don't really understand how all of that is supposed to work. Could someone explain?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return a JavaScript string from a WebAssembly function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353389/how-can-i-return-a-javascript-string-from-a-webassembly-function). The answer I provided in this other question tells you how to pass string in / out of WebAssembly.

Comment: @JFBastien I'm not sure. I've followed these instructions to get started with wasm yesterday-> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/C_to_wasm . When I compile a .cpp file, I get a .js file which I reference via a <script> tag to get access to a Module object in the global scope. I'm not really sure about what you're doing at all. Is your way of things what I should be doing? Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 11):

With Emscripten you can use a virtual file system for WASM.
First, you compile your C/C++ code with `-s FORCE_FILESYSTEM=1` option.
Inside the C/C++, you just work with files as usual, with standard library functions.
At the HTML page you have an `input type=file` element.

Sample JS code to get the file from the input element and pass it into the WASM:

```
function useFileInput(fileInput) {
    if (fileInput.files.length == 0)
        return;
    var file = fileInput.files[0];

    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function () {
        var data = new Uint8Array(fr.result);

        Module['FS_createDataFile']('/', 'filename', data, true, true, true);
        Module.ccall('YourCppFunctionToUtilizeTheFile', null, [], null);

        fileInput.value = '';
    };
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Links:

1. [Emscripten - File System Overview](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/files/file_systems_overview.html)
2. [Here I use the approach, see emulatorAttachFileInput() function](https://github.com/nzeemin/ukncbtl-wasm/blob/master/index.html)

Answer (score 6):

This is a partial answer. It's superior to what I originally did and I feel like it might be closer to what the creators intended. However, I'm still creating more than one copy of the file. Credit to [this post for making it click for me.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875728/pass-a-javascript-array-as-argument-to-a-webassembly-function/41878939#41878939)

This is now my handleFile callback, commented with things I learned.

```
handleFile(e){

    const file = e.currentTarget.files[0];
    if(!(file instanceof Blob)) return;
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = evt => {

        //evt.target.result is an ArrayBuffer. In js, 
        //you can't do anything with an ArrayBuffer 
        //so we have to ???cast??? it to an Uint8Array
        const uint8_t_arr = new Uint8Array(evt.target.result);

        //Right now, we have the file as a unit8array in javascript memory. 
        //As far as I understand, wasm can't directly access javascript memory. 
        //Which is why we need to allocate special wasm memory and then
        //copy the file from javascript memory into wasm memory so our wasm functions 
        //can work on it.

        //First we need to allocate the wasm memory. 
        //_malloc returns the address of the new wasm memory as int32.
        //This call is probably similar to 
        //uint8_t * ptr = new uint8_t[sizeof(uint8_t_arr)/sizeof(uint8_t_arr[0])]
        const uint8_t_ptr = window.Module._malloc(uint8_t_arr.length);

        //Now that we have a block of memory we can copy the file data into that block
        //This is probably similar to 
        //std::memcpy(uint8_t_ptr, uint8_t_arr, sizeof(uint8_t_arr)/sizeof(uint8_t_arr[0]))
        window.Module.HEAPU8.set(uint8_t_arr, uint8_t_ptr);

        //The only thing that's now left to do is pass 
        //the address of the wasm memory we just allocated
        //to our function as well as the size of our memory.
        window.Module.readFile(uint8_t_ptr, uint8_t_arr.length);

        //At this point we're forced to wait until wasm is done with the memory. 
        //Your site will now freeze if the memory you're working on is big. 
        //Maybe we can somehow let our wasm function run on a seperate thread and pass a callback?

        //Retreiving our (modified) memory is also straight forward. 
        //First we get some javascript memory and then we copy the 
        //relevant chunk of the wasm memory into our javascript object.
        const returnArr = new Uint8Array(uint8_t_arr.length);
        //If returnArr is std::vector<uint8_t>, then is probably similar to 
        //returnArr.assign(ptr, ptr + dataSize)
        returnArr.set(window.Module.HEAPU8.subarray(uint8_t_ptr, uint8_t_ptr + uint8_t_arr.length));

        //Lastly, according to the docs, we should call ._free here.
        //Do we need to call the gc somehow?
        window.Module._free(uint8_t_ptr);

    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
}
```

Here is readFile.cpp.

```
#include <emscripten/bind.h>

//We get out pointer as a plain int from javascript
void readFile(const int & addr, const size_t & len){
  //We use a reinterpret_cast to turn our plain int into a uint8_t pointer. After
  //which we can play with the data just like we would normally.
  uint8_t * data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(addr);
  for(size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i){
    data[i] += 1;
  }
}

//Using this command to compile
//  emcc --bind -O3 readFile.cpp -s WASM=1 -s TOTAL_MEMORY=268435456 -o api.js --std=c++11
//Note that you need to make sure that there's enough memory available to begin with.
//I got only 16mb without passing the TOTAL_MEMORY setting.
EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS(my_module) {
  emscripten::function("readFile", &readFile);
}
```