# Why are the functions to reference pointers missing when compiled to WASM?

Tags: c++, c, webassembly, emscripten

I'm trying to get started compiling to WebAssembly from C++ and am generally following along with [this guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/existing_C_to_wasm) as to how to pass image data to WASM code. I've looked [through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41353389/how-can-i-return-a-javascript-string-from-a-webassembly-function) [a](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/guidelines/function_pointer_issues.html) [handful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875728/pass-a-javascript-array-as-argument-to-a-webassembly-function) of other posts, but I'm still fairly lost. Whenever I try to call a function that looks at the data from JS I get errors like: `missing function: _Z6getMatPdii` (the function name seems to depend on what type of data I'm creating). For concreteness the relevant bits of code are:

imageRead.cpp:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

extern "C" {

double* create_buffer(int width, int height) {

  return (double *)malloc(width * height * sizeof(double));

}

}

extern "C" {

void destroy_buffer(double* p) {

  free(p);

}

}

extern "C" {

mat getMat(double* p, int width, int height) {

  return  mat(p, height, width); // Armadillo constructor for matrix already in memory

}

}
```

and the HTML:

```
var Module = {
...
 onRuntimeInitialized: function() {
          // API for preparing image transfers:
          api = {
            create_buffer: Module.cwrap('create_buffer','number',['number','number']),
            destroy_buffer: Module.cwrap('destroy_buffer','',['number']),
            fdtd: Module.cwrap('fdtd_sim',null,['number','number','number']),
          };

          p = api.create_buffer(img.width, img.height);
          Module.HEAP8.set(imageData,p);
...
```

and finally fdtd_2d.cpp:

```
<header stuff>...
#include js_passing.h // Contains headers for imageRead.cpp functions

void fdtd_sim(double* p, int width, int height) {
  arma::mat image = getImage(p, width, height);
  ...do stuff...
```

and for compilation:

```
emcc -o simulation.html obj/fdtd_2d.o obj/imageRead.o -Wall -std=c++14 -Lobj -s USE_SDL=2 -s WASM=1 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s "EXTRA_EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS=['cwrap']" -s ERROR_ON_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS=0 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s SAFE_HEAP=1 -s EMULATE_FUNCTION_POINTER_CASTS=1 -s ASSERTIONS=1 -s "EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=['_fdtd_sim','_create_buffer','_destroy_buffer']" -O2 -I /path/to/armadillo-code/include -lsuperlu_51 -DARMA_DONT_USE_WRAPPER
```

As in the MDN example above, I'm getting image data from a `<canvas>` element which is all working fine, but whenever I try to call `getMat` the code fails with the `missing function: _Z6getMatPdii` error. I've essentially copied the MDN code so I'm a little baffled as to why it's failing.

On compilation, there is an output that `_Z6getMatPdii` is undefined, but I can't figure out where that function is coming from. Also, I've seen other versions of it, e.g. `_Z8getImgPhii` (when I was using CImg to try and read the image data).

So, my question is: what's going on here? It clearly seems to be an issue with referencing pointers, but if anything I'm guessing that some library isn't being included correctly and so the constructor functions aren't present when they should be. If there's a better way to be doing this, I'm all ears. The final output I'm trying to achieve is an `arma::mat` that has the grayscale image data from the `canvas` element. How I get to there is open to interpretation.

Comment: In your example `fdtd_sim` function you are calling `getImage`.  What is that function?  Did you mean `getMat`?  Anyway, Armadillo is a C++ library, so I don't know what you expect to happen when you declare a C interface that returns a C++ type `arma::mat`.  You may need to wrap this type, or convert it to something else that is compatible with C.

Comment: isn't it #include <cstdlib> and c++ idiomatic better?

Comment: paddy -- yes, my mistake I do mean `getMat`. I think the issue is that I wasn't understanding which pieces needed be wrapped in the `extern "C"` environment so emscripten wouldn't clear them out. By leaving the functions as C++ they compile (and run) as expected.

nonock -- probably you are right that would be the more C++ way to include the headers. The guide's I've been following aren't super clear about if code is C or C++ generally, which has me a little thrown off.