# Pass shared array buffer to Rust-generated WASM without wasm-bindgen

Tags: javascript, rust, webassembly, ffi

I would like to pass a shared array buffer into a small Rust processing kernel in a web worker. Since it is simple and numeric, I would like to avoid the complexity of wasm-bindgen.

I have defined a function in `sim.rs`, as follows:

```rust
#![no_main]

#[no_mangle]
pub unsafe extern fn run(world: *mut i32) -> i32 {
        //Note: world.offset_from(ptr::null()) is always 0 here.
        world.add(1).write(255);
        world.read_volatile()
}
```

It is compiled without error using `rustc --target=wasm32-unknown-unknown sim.rs` to `sim.wasm`.

The wasm is loaded and called using the following code in a web worker.

```js
const wasm = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(...)
const calls = wasm.instance.exports

const mem = new Int32Array(5)
mem[0] = 7
console.log('test', calls.run(mem.buffer)) //prints 0, not 7
console.log(mem) //prints Int32Array(5) [7, 0, 0, 0, 0], not [7, 255, 0, 0, 0].
```

The real buffer I'd like to use is a bit under 4gb, vs the 20b used above, so I'd like to avoid copying it every frame I need to do processing. I know this should be possible, since from what I gather it's been a pretty core issue of WASM from the start.

Another solution I tried was to [set the memory as a global](https://github.com/DDR0/Stardust/blob/attempt-2/worker/sim.mjs) when I create the wasm module, but then I can't read the array from Rust because it is not in linear memory reachable with a pointer.

Another solution I was looking at was, since my needs are fairly simple (read from and write to an array), to write that functionality up using WAT. However, I couldn't find any documentation for doing that, especially since I think I had to inject a thing at the module level to import the global.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass a JavaScript array as argument to a WebAssembly function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41875728/pass-a-javascript-array-as-argument-to-a-webassembly-function)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. While it does show an array being passed in, it is lacking in two areas - it relies on using Emscripten, which I can't use for this project due to using Rust vs C++, and it copies the array in with `wasmDsp.HEAP32.set(array, ptr / nByte)` which I can't do due to the size of my array - I would be trying to copy around 1.6tb/s of data, I think. Thanks for having a look though!

Comment: Little update here, but wasm-bindgen has an example raytracer that might do this.