# Emscripten pass array to C++ and change its values

Tags: javascript, webassembly, emscripten

It's my first time working with webassembly and I got to the following problem. A solution, which I dont know how to apply, exists in the official [docs of emscripten](https://emscripten.org/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/Interacting-with-code.html#interacting-with-code-access-memory). I also scanned through the web to find a working solution but none has worked for me so far.

Basically I need to get some array out of my C++ code after it has executed. For this purpose, I made a new function within my C++ code which copies the relevant data to some array which has been allocated within emscripten.

The C++ code looks like this:

```
void copy_to_array(std::vector<float> &vec, float* res){

    std::memcpy(res, vec.begin().base(), sizeof(float) * vec.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
        std::cout << "copying array entry: " << i << " : " << vec[i] << " -> " << res[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE void wasm_get_displacement_x(float* res){
    copy_to_array(wasm_result_displacement_x, res);
}
```

I made a function to copy the result from the internal vector `wasm_result_displacement_x` to the given float array `res`.

I know that the values of the array are not 0 since the `std::cout` call shows the following:
[image]

My code within javascript looks like this:

```js
function getFloatArrayFromFunctionCall(func_name, size) {
    var res_ptr = Module._malloc(size * 4);
    Module.ccall(func_name, null, ["number"], res_ptr);
               
    let mem_view = Module.HEAPF32.subarray(res_ptr, res_ptr + size);

    console.log(mem_view);
    Module._free(res_ptr);
}
getFloatArrayFromFunctionCall("wasm_get_displacement_x", n_nodes)
```

It seems like I made a mistake when trying to read the content of the module memory.
Using the `getValue` approach based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40083041/pass-array-to-c-function-with-emscripten) answer doesnt work either.

I am very happy for any help or advice!

Comment: I made an example how to create c++ objects in java script which wrap arrays of objects using emscripten and WebIDL. https://github.com/werto87/emscripten_webidl

Comment: I am not sure where to look in your code. Does it have a concrete solution for my problem?

Comment: "Basically I need to get some array out of my C++ code after it has executed" You can look in "https://github.com/werto87/emscripten_webidl/blob/main/html/some.html". It shows how to work with java script and c++ and arrays.

Comment: It is a totally different way of communicating between the two of them. In particular I am working with ccall.

Comment: I have no experience with ccall. My suggestion uses webidl

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I figured out the solution by trial and error.
`Module.ccall` is supposed to take an array of arguments it reads.

```js
 function getFloatArrayFromFunctionCall(func_name, size) {
     var res_ptr = Module._malloc(size * 4);
     Module.ccall(func_name, null, ["number"], [res_ptr]);
     var view = Module.HEAPF32.subarray(res_ptr >> 2, (res_ptr >> 2) + size);
     Module._free(res_ptr);
     return view;
 }
```

solves the problem. Hope this is helpfull for anyone stumbling across the same problem.

Comment: Now I get `Module._malloc is not a function` console.log from Browser when I call my C function

Comment: @canbax I needed to add `_malloc` to `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS`