# Passing a JS ArrayBuffer or TypedArray to Emscripten w/o Copying

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten, arraybuffer, typedarray

I have a very large ArrayBuffer (or *TypedArray*) in JavaScript that I want to pass to an emscriptened function. I'd like to pass the raw bytes without incurring a copy.

If my C/C++ function takes an `std::string` as in:

```
void processBuffer(std::string const& buffer)
```

I can get the data, but IIUC, the conversion to `std::string` will incur a copy of the buffer.

Is there a way to pass the raw buffer without a copy?
My access is strictly read-only.

I tried:

```
void processBuffer(const char* str, size_t size);
```

with setting `allow_raw_pointers()` in the `EMSCRIPTEN_BINDINGS`, but this does not seem to work.
What am I missing?

Comment: Isn't `var ptr = Module._malloc(bytes); new Uint8Array(Module.HEAPU8.buffer, ptr, bytes);` good, instead of `new Uint8Array(bytes)` in JS?

Comment: Yes. If the buffer is allocated via `Module._malloc()` and passed directly to the asm.js function expecting a `char* ptr` it will not incur a copy (as was kindly explain to me on the emscripten forum). Will post a full answer later.

Comment: @zakki When reading data from a network or writing to an HTML5 canvas, you can't use a pre-allocated buffer; the buffer is allocated by the browser. It's really odd that emscripten doesn't seem to have a way to directly access native JS objects, even within `EM_ASM` blocks.

Comment: Have you already seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17883799/how-to-handle-passing-returning-array-pointers-to-emscripten-compiled-code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering myself.
As it currently stands, there is no way to allow the emscriptened C/C++ code to access JS allocated memory buffers.

That being said, buffers allocated via `Module._malloc()` *can* be passed "by pointer" when using the C API.

Embinding will add additional copying into the C++ types.

For more info see [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?#!starred/emscripten-discuss/CMfYljLWMvY) thread on the emscripten mailing list.

Comment: I'm tempted to think this should be possible using the File System API.

Comment: I’m not familiar with it. What do you mean? Also note that things may have changed since this was asked and written, notably the publication of WASM.

Comment: I know you can load a file blob in a WorkerFS, but there doesn't seem to be support for an arbitrary ArrayBuffer (in File System API). Accessing them as files sounds feasible and perhaps should be added.